# Tableadapter doesn't update

Tags: c#, tableadapter

i'm trying to update a tableadapter.
This is an my code's example.

```
DestTableAdapter destTableAdapter = new DestTableAdapter();
MissioniDataSet.DestDataTable destDataTable =
           destTableAdapter.GetDataByMissioneID(MissioneID);
for(int i = 0; i < destDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    destRow = (MissioniDataSet.DestRow)destDataTable.Rows[i];
    destRow.AccontoMax = i;
}
destTableAdapter.Update(missioniDataSet.Dest);
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected code..

```
DestTableAdapter destTableAdapter = new DestTableAdapter();
MissioniDataSet.DestDataTable destDataTable =
           destTableAdapter.GetDataByMissioneID(MissioneID);
for(int i = 0; i < destDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    destRow = (MissioniDataSet.DestRow)destDataTable.Rows[i];
    destRow.AccontoMax = i;
}
destTableAdapter.Update(destDataTable);
```

> **You are updating with wrong object. In the Update call replace
>   "missioniDataSet.Dest" with
>   "destDataTable". Becuase you're
>   practically having records in
>   "destDataTable", you must update with
>   "destDataTable" in the Update
>   method.**